# Javascriptcore Framework and NSNotifications

Tags: ios, swift2, nsnotificationcenter, javascriptcore

We need to send a piece of Javascript from the server to an iOS app. This Javascript needs to be running in the background and exchange messages with the main application thread built with Swift.

For instance, the Javascript function will launch and send a piece of text at regular basis to the main thread and the main thread will display this on a UITable.

On the other hand, the Swift will be interacting with the user and changing object values within the javascript context.

Is that possible? If it is possible, how can I send messages between both contexts? with NSNotificationCenter?

Thanks,